# CSS columns in container exceed the column count

Tags: html, css

When specifying `column-count` of 2:

```
.parent {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
.child {
    display: block;
}
```

I get way more than 2 columns if there is a height specified. It grows horizontally instead of vertically, overflowing the max-width rather than overflowing the height.

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/6bk5jb3L/2/

I would like to have it scroll vertically rather than horizontally, and stay limited to the column-count which I have specified.

I can't add extra markup, I have to work with the existing elements.

Comment: The number of child elements isn't fixed by any chance is it?

Comment: @Pluto look at my updated answer, all fixed lol, unless you see a problem with this one too?

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this with flexbox. Remember to use the proper css prefixes.

My solution is here on JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/6bk5jb3L/41/

I also remove the `-webkit-column-count` style.

Below will get rid of the scroll bar for you:

```
.parent::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

**EDIT**
Here is an example of the fix that keeps the `-webkit-column-count` style: http://jsfiddle.net/6bk5jb3L/47/

```
.parent {
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    column-count: 2;
}

.parent::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}

.child {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for expending effort on this. Unfortunately, both solutions do not use columns--they are ordered as rows. The order of the content matters in my situation, sorry I didn't explain that better in the original question, but it truly does need to be columns

Comment: Could you not simply change the `flex-direction` to `column` then?

Answer (score -1):

Since you cannot change the markup, add this JQuery that will wrap your `parent` `<div>` with another `<div>` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6bk5jb3L/12/

**JQuery**

```
$( ".parent" ).wrap( "<div class='parentToTheParent'></div>" );
```

**CSS**

```
.parentToTheParent {

    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
.parent{ width: 100%; -webkit-column-count: 2;}
.child{

    border: solid 1px blue;

}
```

PS the parent to the parent was just for fun, don't over think it lol